# Calling class *simple code*

Tags: python, class

```
class HouseLocation():

    def __init__(self,street_name,x,y):
        self.street_name=street_name
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

      def print_address():
          print '{}: {},{}'.format(street_name,x,y)
```

I assume the code is very simple and explains itself I would assume
now my problem is when I try to run it

> k=HouseLocation('lol lo', 3,7)
>
> k.print_address()

I get the following error message

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> k.print_address()
>
> TypeError: print_address() takes no arguments (1 given)

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Add `self` as parameter to the method

Comment: Methods are passed the object that owns them as the first parameter. By convention, we call this `self` in Python (but `def foobar_method(omg_its_me)` is syntactically valid). Note also that `street_name`, `x`, and `y` aren't defined inside `HouseLocation.print_address`. Since methods get their owners as the first argument, you get to use their attributes, but you have to refer to them as such! (`self.street_name`, `self.x`, `self.y`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of a function should be the `self` parameter.  That is your instance of the class and allows you to get/set properties accordingly.

```
class HouseLocation():

    def __init__(self,street_name,x,y):
        self.street_name=street_name
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

    def print_address(self):
        print '{}: {},{}'.format(self.street_name,self.x,self.y)
```

Answer (score 3):

Remember that methods take the `self` argument implicitly. Change the method code to:

```
  def print_address(self):
      print '{}: {},{}'.format(self.street_name,self.x,self.y)
```

Comment: Upvoted because you also explained the _why_.

Comment: @dana, yeah, forgot about that. Fixed now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`self` is the missing parameter, which is passed as the first argument of all class methods.

```
def print_address(self):
    print '{}: {},{}'.format(self.street_name,self.x,self.y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `self` to `print_address()`

```
def print_address(self):
    print '{}: {},{}'.format(self.street_name, self.x, self.y)
```

Answer (score 1):

`self` is the missing parameter here. The function needs to have at least one argument where one of those is `self` whenever in a class:

```
def print_address(self):
      print '{}: {},{}'.format(self.street_name,self.x,self.y)
```

Then to avoid `NameError`, add `self.` in front of the variables.